# Replace part of String, using regex and vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

My application stores the path of the userdata.dll in a String.

I need to convert this string: `C:\Applications\User\userdata.dll`

into this: `C:\\Applications\\User\\userdata.dll`

All `\` will need to be duplicated, independent on how many `\` the path have.

Something like:

```
Dim defaultPath As String = "C:\Applications\User\userdata.dll"

' Regex
Dim r As Regex = New Regex( ... )

' This is the replacement string
Dim Replacement As String = " ... $1 ... "

' Replace the matched text in the InputText using the replacement pattern
Dim modifiedPath As String = r.Replace(defaultPath,Replacement)
```

Any help on this? I am trying to follow this question:

[How to replace some part of this string with vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368487/how-to-replace-some-part-of-this-string-with-vb-net)

But cant find out how to make this Regex...

Comment: Why do you need a Regex? `String.Replace` works fine: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTnpIi](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTnpIi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Dim pattern As String =  "\\"

Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)

Dim input As String = "C:\Applications\User\userdata.dll"

Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, "\\")

Console.WriteLine(result)
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/G2ywrx)**

If you mean to say that replace any number of `\` to `\\`, then you can use

```
Dim pattern As String =  "\\+"

Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)

Dim input As String = "C:\\\\Applications\User\userdata.dll"

Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, "\\")
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/OZKxx6)**

Comment: Nice answer, but technically, you don't need the character class. You could just use \\ as the pattern.